# Why is the output on this ping outside the subshell?

Tags: bash, ping, subshell

I have a simple script that checks if an interface is connected:

```
connected=$(ping -I $1 -qc 1 8.8.8.8 \
  && echo "connected" \
  || echo "not connected")

echo "$connected" | tail -n1
```

I'm expecting that it should simply return "connected" or "not connected". When I actually use the script I always get back a warning before my output.

```
ping: Warning: source address might be selected on device other than enp0s25.
not connected
```

What is with the warning here, shouldn't it be part of the subshell?

Comment: Aside from redirecting standard error, wouldn't it be much simpler as `if ping ... ; then echo "connected" ; else echo "not connected"; fi`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The warning is sent to `ping`’s standard error, which isn’t captured. If you want to ignore it, redirect it to `/dev/null` explicitly:

```
connected=$(ping -I $1 -qc 1 8.8.8.8 2>/dev/null \
  && echo "connected" \
  || echo "not connected")

echo "$connected" | tail -n1
```